# Evaluate ( if convergent) $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} dx $

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I would like to check whether the improper integral $$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} dx $$ is convergent or not. How can I check convergency? If convergent what is the integral value?

Proceed:  If we substitute $x=\sin^2\theta$, hten we have

$$\int \frac1{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \,dx = \sin^{-1} (2x-1) + C.$$

**Added:**  for $x>1$, integrand is not defined. So if we take $0\leq x\leq 1$, then what we can say about its convergency?

Comment: Are you sure it is not $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx$ instead?

Comment: I think you are right @egreg

Comment: If we take range of integration as [0,1], what will be the result?

Comment: Consider $ \int_{-\frac12}^\frac12 \frac{dx} { \sqrt{\frac14-x^2}}$ symmetric case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $1/\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is only defined over $(0,1)$, so the proposed integral makes no sense. If you want to compute
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx
$$
your substitution is correct: set $x=\sin^2\theta$, with $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$, so
$$
dx=2\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta
$$
and you have
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx=
\int\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}}\,d\theta=
\int 2\,d\theta=2\theta+c
$$
Thus your improper integral becomes
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx=
\int_0^{\pi/2} 2\,d\theta=\Bigl[2\theta\Bigr]_0^{\pi/2}=\pi
$$

Convergence follows also from the fact that
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx=
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx
+
\int_{1/2}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx
=
2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx
$$
and this is convergent by comparison with $\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$

Answer (score 2):

If $x>1$ , then $1-x<0$, henc $x(1-x)<0$ and $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is not defined !

Comment: thank you for point out the  mistake. If we take $0\leq x\leq 1$, then what can we say about the integral? @Fred

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {x \left( 1-x \right) }}}\,{\rm d}x=
\pi
$$

Perhaps try: Complete the square under the radical, trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean $\int_{0}^{\color{red}{1}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$ (the integral $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$ is blatantly divergent, no matter which determination of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ we pick) you may notice that by the substitution $x=u^2$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=2\left[\arcsin u\right]_{0}^{1}=\pi$$
also because $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-u^2}\,du$ is the area of a quarter-circle, equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and by integration by parts

$$ \frac{\pi}{4}=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-u^2}\,du=\left[u\sqrt{1-u^2}\right]_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-u^2}\,du, $$
so that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-u^2}\,du = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$